# Google Data Studio REGEXP_MATCH for multiple URL variations

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

Just started using Google Data Studio, and ran into a problem.

We have a custom downloads report, which displays the full URL of file, and then file name; for example:

> https://website.com/-/media/rak/files/productdocuments/filename.pdf

We also have files in a different location; for example:

> https://website.com/-/media/rak/files/rak-library/filename.pdf

I'm trying to combine both to display in the downloads report, but with only the file name showing - we want to strip out the separate website URLs.

From trawling various websites, including this one, I've got the below `CASE` statement to partially work. It will run the first line, but does not seem to want to run the second line.

The `Event Action` field is what is displaying the full URL and file name.

I'm not 100% sure what the `.*` does, but it seems like a partial match, not exact? When I didn't have this in, it could not find either URLs, so presumed that `REGEXP_MATCH` is looking for an exact match, and I needed to not have the file name included in the path.

--

**Main function**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Action, '[https://website.com/-/media/rak/files/productdocuments/].*' ) THEN Remove TXT 01
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Action, '[https://website.com/-/media/rak/files/rak-library/].*' ) THEN Remove TXT 02
  ELSE Event Action
END
```

***Remove TXT 01***

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Action, 'https://website.com/-/media/rak/files/productdocuments/', '' )
```

***Remove TXT 02***

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Event Action, 'https://website.com/-/media/rak/files/rak-library/', '' )
```

--

I'm not 100% sure if it is user error, but if anyone can supply an idea as to how to get this to work, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by first creating the `Extract_Text` formula below, and then creating the `Main Formula`:

**Formula 1: Extract_Text**

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Event Action, "/([\\w-]+\\.\\w+)\\]?$")
```

***Formula 2: Main Formula***

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Action, "\\[?https://website\\.com/-/media/rak/files/(productdocuments|rak-library)/[\\w-]+\\.\\w+\\]?") THEN Extract_Text
  ELSE Event Action
END
```

***Formula Breakdown***

1. ***Extract_Text***: Captures a range of characters `a-zA-Z0-9_-` after the last `/` in the sequence: [`characters`]`.`[`characters`]
2. ***Main Formula***: If the pattern doesn't match, then values from the `Event Action` field are extracted.

> Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/cfe4ca4a-52ae-4b1e-9bfd-de63dfc0d636) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate.
>   ***EDIT***: The formula now captures `-` to extract `product-name-01.pdf`

[image]